# How to reverse byte order the elegant way? (from big-endian to little-endian)

Tags: python, byte, reverse, python-2.x, swap

Hi all my internet friends!

This is the method I am using right now, not very elegant and not very useful if the hex value gets bigger:

```
"compressed_filled_01" is an hex value, 0x00024680

########## File 00 ##########

# Get the size of file 00 in bytes
file_00_size = os.path.getsize("OPENING_00.LZS")

# 0x5C + file_00_size
modified_file_00_size = 0x5C + file_00_size

# Convert the modified file size to a hexadecimal string
hex_00_converted = hex(modified_file_00_size)[2:].rstrip("L")

# Fill with zeros
filled_00 = str(hex_00_converted).zfill(8)

# Convert from big endian to little endian
little_endian_00 = filled_00[6] + filled_00[7] + filled_00[4] + filled_00[5] + filled_00[2] + filled_00[3] + filled_00[0] + filled_00[1]

# Write to the file
f.write(binascii.unhexlify(little_endian_00))
The result is the expected value, that is 0x80460200
```

Now, there should be a more elegant approach, one that I haven't found yet. I've looked everywhere, even used the OpenIA chat, but to no avail.

Reversing bytearray maybe? Bitwise operators?

PD: I'm on Python 2.7.18 by the way.

Comment: Did you actually start with this number as an integer rather than a string? Then use the struct package to convert it to a byte array in whichever order you want.

Comment: This can't be the whole code, you haven't assigned any value to `compressed_filled_01` in actual code.

Comment: I start getting a file size, not sure if that is int or str, looks like int to me:

# Get the size of file 00 in bytes
file_00_size = os.path.getsize("OPENING_00.LZS")

Comment: " I'm on Python 2.7.18 by the way." Why? (Are you also using Windows 7?)

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. I am also using a set of tools which explicitly say "The tools are not compatible with Python 3", that's why I installed latest Python 2 version. I'll trry to migrate my code to Python 3. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `struct` package to convert integers into byte arrays in big or little endian format:

```
import struct
file_00_size = os.path.getsize("Untitled.ipnb") # Using a file that exists on my system
# '<' is for little-endian, 'I' is for unsigned integer:
bites = struct.pack('<I', file_00_size)
print([hex(b) for b in bites])

>>> ['0x4c', '0x60', '0x0', '0x0']
```

You can copy this back into an out-of-order integer with

```
reversed_value = struct.unpack('>I', bites)
print(hex(reversed_value[0]))

>>> 0x4c600000
```

Comment: First code you posted gives me this error: error: cannot convert argument to integer.

Comment: You should be using `file_00_size` as the argument to `pack`, not any of the later variables you generate after converting the size to a string.

Comment: I get this: TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex.

Comment: What do you see when you print the intermediate values (`file_00_size` and `bites` in my code)?

Comment: print (file_00_size) # 7376  
print (bites) # Ð

Comment: @Green_goblin because you are using Python 2, which **you really shouldn't be using**

Comment: @Green_goblin but you should be able to just use create a `bytearray` from `reversed_value` and it should work like a Python 3 `bytes` object

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, 37 years old and I started learning Python like 5 days ago, so sorry guys. Problem seems to be that my argument is not an integer, hence the problems.

Comment: @Green_goblin right, iterating over a `bytes` object in Python 3 gives your integers. IN Python 2, `bytes` is basically an alias for `str`. This whole situation is at the *core* of the difference between Python 2-3, in Python 3, `str` is equivalent to Python 2 `unicode` objects

Answer (score 0):

My intelligence is not artificial. Sorry for that!
Your message is probably from a legacy protocol that was designed to transport 32 bits data in a protocol designed for 16 bits words. In the era of of 16 to 32 bits transition (1970 to 1990), many schemes were 'invented' to pack 32 bits into 4 bytes:

- B3 B2 B1 B0 (the natural way)
- B2 B3 B0 B1
- B0 B1 B2 B3
- B1 B0 B3 B2

You can convert your payload with a simple loop as this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(payload):
  b = payload[i:i+3] # get a slice (to abbreviate)
  lw = # do some mangling (see later)
  payload[i:i+3] = lw
  i += 4
```

and the mangling may be one of the following:

- lw = (b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]) # natural way
- lw = (b[1], b[0], b[3], b[2]) # for little-endian 16 bits-word
- lw = (b[3], b[2], b[1], b[0])
- lw = (b[2], b[3], b[0], b[1])

And that's all.
Note that this answer did not require 168 GPU and 150J energy.